# Thinkpad USB 3.0 docking station disconnects and reconnects

Tags: 16.04, usb, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T450s with a USB 3.0 docking station (also Lenovo), running 16.04 LTS. The docking station is connected to a few USB peripherals, ethernet, and a DisplayLink monitor. The station periodically disconnects and then (very quickly, ~1 second) reconnects again. These events typically happen multiple times per day, but I have gone a few days without incident before. As far as I know, all of my relevant drivers (including DisplayLink) are up to date.

My dmesg is also flooded with (I believe unrelated) spam, that comes in constantly whether or not the dock is disconnecting:

```
[373168.536341] [drm:drm_wait_vblank [drm]] *ERROR* Unsupported type value 0x4000041, supported mask 0x7400003f
[373168.553436] [drm:drm_wait_vblank [drm]] *ERROR* Unsupported type value 0x41, supported mask 0x7400003f
```

Because of the dmesg spam, I don't currently have a log of the disconnect-reconnect. I will include one when I am able to capture it, but I do not believe it shows anything unusual beyond the list of devices connected to the docking station disconnecting and then reconnecting again.

Thanks!

Edit: The results from dmesg immediately after a disconnect are below:

```
[499047.292100] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 53
[499047.292104] usb 3-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 55
[499047.294353] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5 enxe04f4359a6b1: unregister 'cdc_ncm' usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1, CDC NCM
[499047.321377] usb 3-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 54
[499047.333135] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_disconnect:611 (dev=1) Disconnected from ffff8801c08dd400
[499047.333139] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[499047.333178] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:593 (dev=-1) An unknown connection to ffff8801c08dd400 tries to close us
[499047.333180] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:594  - ignoring
[499047.341965] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[499047.379218] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=-1) Notifying crtc state: 3
[499047.379221] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_crtc_state:387 Painter is not connected!
[499047.602454] usb 3-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[499047.717203] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=1014
[499047.717209] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[499047.717212] usb 3-3: Product: TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock  
[499047.717214] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: LENOVO                 
[499047.733011] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[499047.735168] hub 3-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[499048.148156] usb 3-3.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[499048.165704] usb 3-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=4340
[499048.165712] usb 3-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[499048.165716] usb 3-3.1: Product: ThinkPad USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
[499048.165718] usb 3-3.1: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[499048.165720] usb 3-3.1: SerialNumber: 4551152301011274J1YY
[499048.221380] usb 3-3.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=511), cval->res is probably wrong.
[499048.221383] usb 3-3.1: [15] FU [Lenovo Audio Playback Volume] ch = 6, val = -8176/0/16
[499048.222201] usb 3-3.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
[499048.222206] usb 3-3.1: [12] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 2, val = -4592/7680/16
[499048.252543] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5: MAC-Address: e0:4f:43:59:a6:b1
[499048.252548] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5: setting rx_max = 16384
[499048.252663] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5: setting tx_max = 16384
[499048.252913] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5 usb0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1, CDC NCM, e0:4f:43:59:a6:b1
[499048.385196] usb 3-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[499048.487299] usb 3-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=1015
[499048.487303] usb 3-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[499048.487305] usb 3-3.4: Product: TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock  
[499048.487306] usb 3-3.4: Manufacturer: LENOVO                 
[499048.492208] hub 3-3.4:1.0: USB hub found
[499048.492376] hub 3-3.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[499049.272800] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5 enxe04f4359a6b1: renamed from usb0
[499049.310745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxe04f4359a6b1: link is not ready
[499049.310819] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxe04f4359a6b1: link is not ready
[499050.607303] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5 enxe04f4359a6b1: 1000 mbit/s downlink 1000 mbit/s uplink
[499050.623303] cdc_ncm 3-3.1:1.5 enxe04f4359a6b1: network connection: connected
[499050.623335] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enxe04f4359a6b1: link becomes ready
[499050.751126] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:593 (dev=-1) An unknown connection to ffff8801efe9fe00 tries to close us
[499050.751128] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:594  - ignoring
[499050.756546] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_connect:572 (dev=1) Connected with ffff8801efe9fe00
[499050.756549] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:75 (dev=1) Painter is connected
[499050.756608] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=1) Notifying crtc state: 3
[499050.759243] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:75 (dev=1) Painter is connected
[499050.759248] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:215 (dev=1) 00 ff ff
[499050.793728] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_mode_changed_notify:505 (dev=1) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1080@60; bpp 32; 
[499050.793730] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_mode_changed_notify:506 pixel format 875713112
[499050.793735] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=1) Notifying crtc state: 0
[499050.793737] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_dpms_notify:468 (dev=1) Notifying dpms mode: 0
```

Comment: In case you did not solve the problem: Can you rule out hardware problems? I found that the dock connectors can wear out. I replaced a ThinkPad because I frequently had to undock and redock multiple times until it connected properly. The dock was still O.K. and worked flawlessly with another ThinkPad.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same cases.